# How to pass multiple JSON file to Onservable Arrays when value in one file is used as argument for another file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am attempting to use `$.getJSON` to call two json file and assigned their values to `observableArrays`: Currently the JSON data is hard coded to the `observableArray`. [Example fiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/9nd82f6e/4/)

I attempted to do this:

```
        self.CountryData = ko.observableArray([]);
        self.CountryDetailData = ko.observableArray([]);

        $.when( $.getJSON( 'country.json' ), $.getJSON( 'country-detail.json' ))
.done(function( country, countryDetail ) {

            self.CountryData(country[0]);
            self.CountryDetailData(countryDetail[0]);
});
```

*Next, I attempted to merge both files:*

```
var data = country[0].concat(countryDetail[0]);
```

Finally, for experimental purpose, I simply manually combined both files by simple taking the values from one file and placing it into the other but it is not given me the expected result.

Here is a working [JS Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/9nd82f6e/4/) using the hard-coded JSON data.

Instead of hardcode JSON data, how do I call JSON files and assigned to observables?

I cannot get this section of code to work:

```
self.CountryDetails = function (country) {
            var data = ko.computed(function () {

                return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.CountryDetailData(), function (item) {
                    return item.CountryId === country.CountryId;
                });
            });

            self.CountryId(data()[0].CountryId);
            self.Location(data()[0].Location);
            self.Coordinates(data()[0].Coordinates);
            self.Coastline(data()[0].Coastline);
            self.Climate(data()[0].Climate);
            self.Terrain(data()[0].Terrain);
        }
```

Error: `Message: CountryId is not defined;`

*UPDATE:*

I decided to apply a native approach so that I can get the CountryID from the table and pass as argument: I also place the $.getJSON in the function in which it is being used so that the result is available when executed:

*Code:*

```
self.CountryDetails = function (country) {

$.getJSON( 'country-detail.json')
.done(function( result ) {

  self.CountryDetailData(result);

  var data = ko.computed(function () {

      return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.CountryDetailData(), function (item) {

         // get CountryId from view
          var cId = $('#country-list tbody tr:first-child td:first-child').html();

      /*  Because I am unable to get ID on page load, I am doing a work-around.
          If the country parameter is undefine then use the alternative method to
          get the countryId from the first row or and first cell. */
          currentId = (country === undefined ? cId : country.CountryId);

          return item.CountryId ===  currentId;

      });
  });

  self.CountryId(data()[0].CountryId);
  self.Location(data()[0].Location);
  self.Coordinates(data()[0].Coordinates);
  self.Coastline(data()[0].Coastline);
  self.Climate(data()[0].Climate);
  self.Terrain(data()[0].Terrain);

});
}
```

Now I am able to use a JSON file and load the additional data same as when the JSON values are hardcoded.

Comment: Can you show what your server-side JSON looks like?

Comment: You've written a very, very long and detailed question. However I still don't know what the problem is. Can you simplify it, so that it's easyly undertsnadable? I think there is much more on the question than it's needed to understand it.

Comment: Is it your problem simply to mix-in the properties of one json file with the properties in the other? If so, go, and simplify your question to ask just this. If not, try to only show the code and question that you need. Thank you.

Comment: In a nutshell, I need to use `$.getJSON` to access the JSON data files rather than hard-coding their values. Please look at the fiddle, it shows the `JSON` data in the code, which is what I want to replace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically want a `CountrySelector`, something that has a list of continents and countries and offers the functionality of selecting a continent first and a a country based on that.

For simplicity, let's remove all the Ajax and reduce it to a pure, data-centric model:

```
function CountrySelector(data) {
    var self = this;

    // base data
    self.countries = ko.observableArray(data.countries);
    self.continents = ko.observableArray(data.continents);

    // state data
    self.selectedContinent = ko.observable();
    self.selectedCountry = ko.observable();
    self.selectedCountryDetails = ko.observable();
    self.filteredCountries = ko.computed(function () {
        var selectedContinent = self.selectedContinent();
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.countries(), function (country) {
            return selectedContinent && country.Continent === selectedContinent;
        });
    });

    // subscriptions
    self.filteredCountries.subscribe(function (countries) {
        self.selectedCountry(countries[0]);
    });
    self.selectedCountry.subscribe(function (country) {
        var selectedDetails = ko.utils.arrayFirst(data.details, function (details) {
            return details.CountryId === country.CountryId;
        });
        self.selectedCountryDetails(selectedDetails);
    });

    // state init
    self.selectedContinent(self.continents[0]);
}
```

This expects to be initialized with a data object:

```
{
    continents: [/* ... list of continent names ... */],
    countries: [/* ... list of country objects ... */],
    details: [/* ... list of country detail objects ... */],  
}
```

Now you have something that works independently of the *kind* of data source (you could initialize it with hard-coded data, from localStorage, from another viewmodel, via Ajax, whatever).

---

To initialize it via Ajax, we send two requests:

```
var countryReq = $.getJSON('country.json');
var countryDetailReq = $.getJSON('country-detail.json');
```

wait for them and massage the data into shape (jQuery's `.then()` comes in handy here):

```
var combinedData = $.when(countryReq, countryDetailReq).then(function (countries, details) {
    // figure out disintct continent names
    var continents = ko.utils.arrayMap(countries, function (country) {
            return country.Continent;
        });
    continents = ko.utils.arrayGetDistinctValues(continents);
    continents.sort();

    // assemble the data the viewmodel expects
    return {
        countries: countries,
        continents: continents,
        details: details
    };
});
```

As soon as this is done we can apply bindings:

```
combinedData.done(function (data) {
    ko.applyBindings( new CountrySelector(data) );
});
```

into a view like this:

```html
<ul data-bind="with: selectedCountryDetails">
    <li>CountryId: <span data-bind="text: CountryId"></span></li>
    <li>Location: <span data-bind="text: Location"></span></li>
    <li>Coordinates: <span data-bind="text: Coordinates"></span></li>
    <li>Coastline: <span data-bind="text: Coastline"></span></li>
    <li>Climate: <span data-bind="text: Climate"></span></li>
    <li>Terrain: <span data-bind="text: Terrain"></span></li>
</ul>

<div id="country-select">
    <select data-bind="options: continents, value: selectedContinent"></select>
</div>

<table id="country-list">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>CountryID</th>
            <th>Country Name</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>Continent</th>
            <th>CountryAbbr</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: filteredCountries">
        <tr data-bind="
            click: $root.selectedCountry,
            clickBubble: false,
            css: {
                active: CountryId === $root.selectedCountry().CountryId
            }
        ">
            <td data-bind="text: CountryId"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: Country"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: City"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: Continent"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: CountryAbbr"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Tomalak: In addition to clicking the rows in the table and displaying the country information (detail). How do I also load the detail of the first row. So each time a change is made I can subscribed to the change and display the detail of the first country whenever a continent is changed. This way the details information is never empty.

Comment: My code loads the detail of the first row. Did you try it?

Comment: Attempted to use the above solution but it is not working: `continents is undefined`. Painfully, there are no errors or messages in the log. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @Asynchronous Except from a tiny mistake that I have just corrected, my code works fine.

Comment: Hey Tomalak, if you have a working code, can you please post/create a Fiddle?

Comment: I think you can create a working jsFiddle from that as well. I have given you everything *except* copy-and-paste code, please try to go the last step yourself.

Comment: Thank you again, I am very new to knockout and this will help me better understand ways to get things working.